# Всплывающее окно JVM

Tags: gui, java, jvm

Пишу оповещалку, основной пользовательской частью которой будет появляющееся окошко с сообщением (текст + картинка [в будущем]) вроде того, что вы могли видеть в Qip (правый нижний угол) [image]

Сейчас это JFrame c setUndecorated(true). Проблема в том, что отображается это всё как окно, в панели задач появляется Java-иконка для каждого из них. Ну ещё это сбивает фокус с рабочего окна. Мне бы отрисовывать в заданном месте поверх всех окон (совсем как в Qip), чтобы можно было отлавливать нажатие на нём кнопок мыши.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, через что это сделать. Не привязан к awt, только к JVM-языкам

Comment: Попробуйте использовать JPanel

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать для подобных целей не `JFrame`, а `JWindow`.

`JFrame` есть окно приложения. Отображаться в панели задач - его основная обязанность. `JWindow` - это вспомогательное окно, через него реализуются выпадающие меню и подобные вещи. Оно никогда не отображается в панели задач